# How to manage scope session in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a spring boot app with a controller layer, a service layer and a persistance layer. And i used spring security with JWT to provide the login process and to manage http sessions. I injected the service in the controller as follows :

```
@RestController
@ComponentScan(basePackages ={"com.example.service"})
@RequestMapping("/releve")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://192.168.1.13:4200")
public class ReleveController {
    
    @Autowired
    ReleveService releveService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder encoder;
    
    
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping(value="/listNiveaux")
    public List<Niveau> listNiveaux() {
        return releveService.listNiveaux();
    }
    
    
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping(value="/modifNiveaux",consumes = "application/json")
    public void modifNiveaux(@RequestBody Niveau niveau) {
        releveService.modifNiveaux(niveau);
    }
    
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping(value="/delNiveaux",consumes = "application/json")
    public void delNiveaux(@RequestBody Niveau niveau) {
        releveService.delNiveaux(niveau);
    }
    
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping(value="/sauvegardeNiveau")
    public void sauvegardeNiveau() {
        releveService.sauvegardeNiveau();
    }   
}
```

Here are the annotations that i used in my service :

```
@Service(value = "ReleveService")
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example.releve.repository", entityManagerFactoryRef="entityManagerFactory")
public class ReleveServiceImpl implements ReleveService {
...
}
```

The problem is that despite the fact that the scope is session, the service ( or the bean ) is reinstanciated in every REST request : it does not get destroyed however, i used @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy to verify that it does not have the same behavior as the request scope.
How do i solve this ?

PS : i use Angular for the front-end app and there is another controller class for the login web service.

Comment: Try to do it without proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS

Comment: I tried to do it without using ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS but the program did not compile.